# You must specify a period

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have created the following time series:

```
year_2007_gap_ts = pd.date_range('2007-01-01', periods=365, freq='D')
```

which produces the following dtype:

```
dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=365, freq='D'
```

When I try to decompose with the following:

```
result = seasonal_decompose(year_2007_gap_ts, model='additive')
print(result.trend)
print(result.seasonal)
print(result.resid)
print(result.observed)
```

I get a ***ValueError: You must specify a period or x must be a pandas object with a PeriodIndex or a DatetimeIndex with a freq not set to None***

Any idea as to what is causing this error and how to fix it?

Comment: It looks like `seasonal_decompose` expects a `pandas.Series` with a `pandas.DatetimeIndex`.  You can see [here](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/96c41cd1542880bdc98274f571416ea9b1dfac7e/statsmodels/tsa/seasonal.py#L147) that is trying to get the index of the pandas object and then getting the `inferred_freq` property of the index.   Since you are passing a `pandas.DatetimeIndex` directly this line is returning `None`